# which function of mechanize is equal with urllib.urlencode

Tags: python, mechanize, urllib

urllib.urlencode could encode url's params.  It seems no likely function in Mechanize.

So, I have to use urllib and Mechanize, because I only need urlencode.

Any function could implement the same task like urllib.urlencode in Mechanize

Comment: Libraries aren't mutually exclusive, you're allowed to import more than one...

Answer (score 3):

Why would `mechanize` have it? It's already in `urllib`, which *comes with* Python.

Answer (score 0):

`mechanize` actually uses `urllib` and `urllib2` for most tasks that involve urls.

Since this functionality already exists in `urllib/2` (as mentioned by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams) there's no need for it to be implemented elsewhere. When coding you import *all* the libraries that have functionality you need to use.